# Writing a a char * in a array and after in a file

Tags: c

This is my piece of code:

```
char sentence[400];
FILE *f;

const char *appname = application_name; //where the application_name comes from the program
strcat(sentence,appname);
... //I add more string 

f = fopen ("Test.txt", "a+");
...
fprintf(f,"%s\n",sentence);
fclose (f);
```

An example of result is: `àB®pgAdmin III - Browser`
What is `àB®`?

When I add `printf("%s",appname)` I can see the right name in console, in the case of the example above `pgAdmin III - Browser`, why?

Comment: If you use unicode, read `man fwprintf`

Comment: char sentence[400]={0}; should work fine for you...

Comment: using gcc, it would lead to an "using an uninitialised value" error. So initialize sentence, which in C is per se some random value (on the stack)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sentence` is uninitialized, and you're adding something to it. What you end up with is random garbage followed by your text. Either use `strcpy` or initialize the `sentence` variable.

Comment: I added `strcpy(sentence,"\0");` and now it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DarkCoffee You could simply write `char sentence[400] = {'\0'};` instead. And if this post answered your question, please accept it as the correct one by clicking the check mark to the left side of it.

Answer (score 0):

Change strcat to strcpy your program will work fine.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
    char sentence[400];
    const char *appname = "string_check";
    strcpy(sentence,appname);
    printf("%s\n", sentence);
    return 0;
    }
```